# Data binding a TabControl using MVVM

Tags: wpf

I don't have a great deal of experience with WPF. What I would like to do is to create a Tab control that gets its list of Tab Items from a property in my view model, and I would also like to have a method in my view model called when the user changes the current tab. Can someone point me to some sample code that demonstrates this?

Answer (score 0):

This was the tutorial that helped me to learn WPF/MVVM. It has an example project with a TabControl. It's by Josh Smith, one of experts on MVVM.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx